# LED blink circuit with push button

Tags: led, circuit-analysis, logic-gates, breadboard

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIEK9y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am trying to build a circuit on a breadboard that consists of two LEDs and a push button.

Using the button, I would like for the LEDs to blink singularly for 1 second on and 1 second off.

Using the button blinks both LEDs simultaneously or blink at the opposite time.

I think I need a logic gate but I am not sure if the AND is a good idea.

Could someone give me some assistance? I have figured out how to get one LED to light through the push button being pressed.

Comment: Welcome! Please draw a schematic of what you have done so far and a truth table of how it’s supposed to operate. If you click on edit and the schematic symbol, a schematic editor opens.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. A schematic is better than words. You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: thank you @winny and Transistor I added a schematic

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this behaviour.

```
                    ___________________
SW1 _______________|           
      __    __    __    __    __    __   
D1  _|  |__|  |__|  |__|  |__|  |__|  |
      __    __    _  __    __    __   
D2  _|  |__|  |__| ||  |__|  |__|  |__|
```

*Figure 1. Timing diagram.*

This can be achieved with an XOR gate.

*Table 1. XOR truth table.*

```
SW1 D1  D2
 0   0   0  
 0   1   1
 1   0   1
 1   1   0
```

Try this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWQPrI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Use an XOR to provide the desired logic.*

It's worth learning how to draw a timing diagram. It enables you to clearly communicate the desired function of many systems.

Apologies for the 555 layout but the CircuitLab symbol has the pinout badly arranged. In any event, it wouldn't simulate for me.

Note that in your schematic D1 doesn't blink.